# Using regex to capture authentication token

Tags: manual-testing, jmeter

I would like to know how do I use the regex in jmeter to capture tokens.

Below this the regex I have created
[image]

And I have pass the values
[image]

And this is the end results
[image]

I'm suppose to get something like this admin:1448270860004:8b54935ad909437ed271f93c4487cdda. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you post that html code where it is showing generated token?

Comment: Can you please post the response from where you want to extract token.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is capturing one character in the range between the square brackets. Try:

```
([0-9A-Za-z]*:[0-9A-Za-z]*)
```

You can use a website to test regex in real time like this one http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the Auth token to enable login authentication in the request. Here is a [tutorial](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743663-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication-) on a means of accomplishing this task.